# Preserving colours while importing HTML to Android

Tags: android, html

I'm importing HTML to my app with this code:

```
MyTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(""));
```

HTML is importing, but colors are not. How can I import HTML with colors?

Here is some sample HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MY HTML CODES</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>MY HTML!</h3>

<p>This HTML <span style="color:#FF0000;"><strong> has a larger .</strong></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a spannable:

```
String myText  = "How <i>are</i> <b>you</b>? "+
       "<font color='green'>Nice</font> <font color='red'>to</font> meet you!";
MyTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

***Edit***: you can get different color using the `font` tag.

Comment: Could you please explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question?

Comment: Not sure if this is an option for the OP but he could use the `color` attribute in a `font` tag.

Answer (score 0):

`Html.fromHtml()` does not support `<span>` elements or `style` attributes, let alone `<head>` or `<title>` and such.

You will either need to write your own parser for this, or convert this HTML into something that `Html.fromHtml()` will support (e.g., `<font color="...">`), or convert this HTML into something that [my CWAC-RichTextUtils library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richtextutils) will support.

Comment: what is CWAC-RichTextUtils? and how can I use? please show me a example. (I'm using html. Because I want write richtext in android.Is there an easier way?)

Comment: @EnesCeylan: Details are in [the CWAC-RichTextUtils library `README`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richtextutils). There is also [a demo project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richtextutils/tree/master/demo) and [some test cases](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richtextutils/tree/master/richtextutils/src/androidTest/java/com/commonsware/cwac/richtextutils/test) in the repo as well.

Answer (score -1):

You should display your HTML in a WebView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

```
String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```